# Good way to null check a long list of parameters

Tags: java, methods

Suppose I have a long set of of parameters all of the same type for some method. I have a similar operation to do on each parameter (if they are not null). Assume I have no control over the method signature since the class implements an interface.

For example.. something simple like this. Set of String params..

```
public void methodName(String param1, String param2, String param3, String param4){

    //Only print parameters which are not null: 

    if (param1 !=null)
        out.print(param1);

    if (param2 !=null)
        out.print(param2);

    if (param3 !=null)
        out.print(param3);

    if (param4 !=null)
        out.print(param4);
}
```

Is there any way I can iterate through the list of String parameters to check if they are not null and print them without having to reference each variable separately?

Comment: Conceivably by using varargs but that would change the semantics of your method.

Comment: If the interface is defined by you then I would suggest to change the signature of the method to `String ... param` or varargs as they are called.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10951671/best-way-to-check-null-for-objects-in-java/10951834#10951834

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can simply do

```
for (String s : Arrays.asList(param1, param2, param3, param4)) {
    if (s != null) {
        out.print(s);
    }
}
```

or

```
for (String s : new String[] {param1, param2, param3, param4}) {
    if (s != null) {
        out.print(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could write your own method with var args and invoke it from your methodName function

`check(param1, param2, param3)`

```
static void check (String ... allParams)
{
   for (String param : allParams) {
        checkNotNull(param); // guava function checkNotNull 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The shortest I could think of is

```
public void methodName(String param1, String param2, String param3, String param4) {
    if(Arrays.asList(param1, param2, param3, param4).contains(null))
        throw new RuntimeException("Supply all params");
}
```